# UITextView reporting incorrect height

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextView with a width of 240. Monitoring the text width shows that it is wrapping the text when the text width >= 224.

In this situation, where the UITextView wraps the text onto the next line, but the length of the text is not greater than 240, the text height is being reported as if it was a single line of text, rather than the height of two lines (since the UITextView wrapped it).

Any ideas why this is happening and how i can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView and there are some default insets applied—8 pixels on both the left and right side. I have never managed to find a way to get rid of them.

Comment: THat makes sense, since the 8 pixels either side gives me the difference between 224 and 240. But what i dont understand is why, if the textview knows to wrap the text at 224, why does is not report the correct height of text until the length of the text exceeds 240 pixels. Im going to try dabbling with the content insets.......